# Ubuntu only detecting 3 gamepads at a time

Tags: gamepad

Im trying to connect 4 gamepads at once over USB, but my computer seems to only recognize 3 at a time. They all work individually, but no matter what order or port I plug them into, the 4th controller is never detected. `lsusb` correctly identifies all 4 controllers.

I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to even start debugging this issue because Google results are flooded with articles on how to get an individual controller to work.

**Edit:** I was able to get the 4th controller to work by unplugging some other USB devices. Still, I'd like to know if there is a setting or reason for the limit.

Comment: If removing other USB devices makes them all work again, then the issue may be that the USB bus/headers behind the scenes on the hardware board don't have enough bandwidth or don't have enough power collectively to power all the devices enough for them to be functional.

Comment: If it is a lack of power there will be error notices reported in `/var/log/`  If the USB complies to modern standards:  `usb-devices | grep 'Product=\|MxPwr'` and `watch -n1 'lsusb -v|egrep "^Bus|MaxPower"'` are the 2 commandss to watch power consumption. You might need a powered HUB instead of a built-in.

Comment: Thank you both, I'll try these suggestions out.

Comment: How many `/dev/input/js#` devices are created? Does `evtest` see input events from the undetected controller? Which software are you trying to use your gamepads with, and is it ported from another OS like Windows?